# Apk for android tv I have developed doesn't work and is not displayed on bluestack emulator

Tags: android, television

I have done customize android tv apk for alltv self.
so it works on android studio emulator well.
but after build apk for this , I tried to install on bluestack emulator.
The apk's icon was displayed and soon it disappeared.
I don't know why it disapper.
Also, i tried to install apk into xiao mi tv box, but it didn't install.

Comment: can you paste your androidmanifest.xml here?

Comment: Please provide one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example